# Sort XML document alphabetically in C#

Tags: c#, xml

In C#, what is the best way to sort an XML document alphabetically - both elements and attributes? For example, if I start with b.xml it should become with a.xml:

[image]

For now, I'm thinking about recursively traversing all elements and for each element I'll remove its child elements and then add them again in alphabetical order, and do the same for attributes.

Is that the approach I should take or is there a better way or perhaps a ready-made function?

Comment: What are you trying to do? The order may matter, depending on what the XSD says. Changing the order may change the meaning of the document. If you want to *read* the elements in a certain order, you can apply `OrderBy`, especially if you use XDocument and LINQ-to-XML. If you want to also write the elements in a new order, you'll have to create a new document and add the ordered nodes recursively

Comment: Why do you want to do this? XML is structured data where the ordering of elements can be significant (can you imagine an alphabetically-ordered HTML document?).

Comment: `perhaps a ready-made function?` no because that's a very specialized feature that may actually change the meaning of the document. While it may make sense for diffing, it would cause problems with real documents. Imagine the steps in a workflow, or legs in an air trip. It's not that hard to do though using LINQ - you can already traverse a tree using iterators and `OrderBy` offers ordering

Comment: If you want to diff two XML documents, you could use set operations which *don't* care about order. If you want to order the XML data so you can use a merge tool on the other hand, ordering makes sense. Many diff tools can ignore the order of XML elements though. On the other hand, you could load two XDocuments and compare them using iterators. If you could come up with a way to identify tokens with a key, you could flatten the XDocument to the tokens and compare the two token streams using set operations

Comment: I am trying to sort the XML documents alphabetically, as the question states. I am not trying to do anything other than sorting them alphabetically. This is exactly what I want and this is exactly what my question states.

Comment: to keep long story short: there's nothing built in, you need to implement your own `IXmlSerializable` for that.

Comment: Define "best way" and "better way".  Why not just take that approach and see if it meets your needs and ask for (quantifiable) improvements if it doesn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer is similar to yours without the need for remove

```csharp
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement sortedXml = Sort_XML.sort(doc.Root);
        }
    }
    public class Sort_XML
    {
        static public XElement sort(XElement root)
        {
            XElement sortedRoot = new XElement(root.Name.LocalName);
            sortRecursive(root, sortedRoot);
            return sortedRoot;
        }
        public static void sortRecursive(XElement parent, XElement sortedRoot)
        {
            foreach (XElement child in parent.Elements().OrderBy(x => x.Name.LocalName))
            {
                XElement childElement = new XElement(child.Name.LocalName);
                sortedRoot.Add(childElement);
                foreach(XAttribute attribute in child.Attributes().OrderBy(x => x.Name.LocalName))
                {
                    childElement.Add(new XAttribute(attribute.Name.LocalName, attribute.Value));
                }
                if (child.HasElements) sortRecursive(child, childElement);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, after some experimenting I came up with a function that works on my test file.

```
private static void SortXml(XmlElement node)
{
    // Load the child elements into a collection.
    List<XmlElement> childElements = new();
        
    foreach (XmlElement childNode in node.ChildNodes)
    {
        childElements.Add(childNode);

        // Call recursively if the child is not a leaf.
        if (childNode.HasChildNodes)
        {
            SortXml(childNode);
        }
    }

    // Load the attributes into a collection.
    List<XmlAttribute> attributes = new();

    foreach (XmlAttribute attrib in node.Attributes)
    {
        attributes.Add(attrib);
    }

    node.RemoveAll();

    // Re-add the child elements (sorted).
    foreach (var childNode in childElements.OrderBy(element => element.Name))
    {
        node.AppendChild(childNode);
    }

    // Re-add the attributes (sorted).
    foreach (var childNode in attributes.OrderBy(attrib => attrib.Name))
    {
        node.Attributes.Append(childNode);
    }
}
```

I'll test it more thoroughly later.